# Send HTTP Request onClick on ActionButton - Firefox addon

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

What's my outcome? I am creating an addon and I want to send a HTTP request when the ActionButton is clicked. The data that will be transfered to the server include the URL of the tab and the content of the page.

I tried to create a log message and grabbing it from the console(listener). Turns out that doesn't work at all. Secondly, I tried to inject(pageMod) contentScript into the website when the button is clicked. It doesn't work that well too. The code is executed several times instead of once.

Code: main.js

```
var button = buttons.ActionButton({
 id: "bookmark-link",
 label: "Bookmark this website",
 icon: {
   "16": "./status-bar.png",
   "32": "./toolbar-large.png",
   "64": "./toolbar-large.png"
 },
 onClick: function() {

     log("triggered!"); // I need to make the Ajax GET request here

 }

});
```

This problem kept me awake the whole night and I can't find any solution that works great. So I try to ask for help here. I appreciate your time!

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Request module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/request)?

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. Thank you

Comment: Can we see the code? Where did it go wrong?

Comment: "The code is executed several times instead of once." You can solve that by adding `attachTo: ["top"]` in you pageMod constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/request) module in your onClick handler.

If you really want to use a content script then do:

```
onClick: function() {
    require('sdk/tabs').activeTab.attach({
      contentScriptFile: require('sdk/self').data.url('request-maker.js'),
    })
}
```